# Fire jQuery event when target does not match selector

Tags: jquery, events

I've got the following markup:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class=expand>click me</a>
                <span>some other content</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                click me too
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I'm attaching a click handler for the rows to the table:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr :not(".expand")', function(evt) {
    if (! $(evt.target).is(selector)) {
        console.log('event is firing even though target doesnt match the selector!!!');
    } else {
        console.log('event is firing as expected');
    }
});

var selector = $('table').data('events').click[0].selector;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronj1335/vQm6X/10/)

I want the event to fire only when it originates at an element that matches the `tr :not(".expand")` selector (the `else` part of the conditional), but the event fires regardless.

**How do I bind the callback to the event at the `<table>` element such that it only fires when it's not a `.expand` element that is clicked?**

**Clarification:** the event handler should still be executed if the user clicks in the `<span>some other content</span>`

Comment: I'm confused. So you want to have everything in the tr clickable, but you want the expand element to not bubble after it's been clicked?

Comment: that's correct.  the expand element already has a click handler elsewhere, so i just want to handle the clicks that aren't on the expand element.

Comment: Check my answer to stop propagation of the expand click. Should handle what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are wanting this:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr td:not(:has(".expand"))', function(evt) {
    console.log("Event only fires when clicking something that doesn't contain an expando");
});

var selector = $('table').data('events').click[0].selector;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PAL4a/)

Comment: this won't fire when the user clicks anywhere in the 'td' that's not the 'a' tag.  i still want the event handler called if the user clicks in the 'td' tag but not in the 'a' tag.  i'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.is(...)` and `event.target`:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr :not(".expand")', function(evt) {
    if ($(evt.target).is('tr :not(".expand")')) {
        alert('clicked it!');
    }
    else {
        alert('not')
    }
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/h9yh7/

Comment: this is exactly what i'm doing in the question.  i know that i can do it this way, but it seems like i'm repeating myself b/c i specify the same selector when i attach the event.  is it possible to not repeat myself?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process .expand, and not trigger the row click,

```
$('table').on('click', '.expand', function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation(); 
    console.log('expand clicked!');
});
```

[`jQuery.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: i want to process the opposite of this, when the user clicks on something other than the .expand

Comment: Which your code already handles. It appeared to me that you were having trouble getting the clicks on expand to stop activating the row click.